# Is it possible to construct vertex on GPU from a non-XYZ vertex buffer?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, simd

I'm writing a particle simulation where the logic is updated using [Intel AVX](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions). I'm using a SoA approach to maximize my "SIMD-friendliness" but I shuffle the particle position components into XYZ-format
when updating the vertex buffer.

Is it possible to exclude the shuffle part and simply pass the vertex data in
XXYYZZ-format and construct each vertex in a shader stage?

My first thought was using three vertex buffers with **x**, **y** and **z** components separated and construct each vertex using the same subscript index to access the x, y and z component of a vertex.

I'm aware that this is **not** the conventional way but I would like to emphasize that this is just an experiment. Perhaps anyone got some knowledge about this approach (if it is even possible) and/or could point me in the right direction? Perhaps there is a name to it aswell?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no restriction on how you feed the GPU with your vertices. You can customize the input layout to read values from any number of vertex buffers, in your example, you will have at least three elements. In the vertex shader, you receive your three elements as three scalars and swizzle them back. The only real limitation is that each value are at the same index in each buffer.

In regards to performance, unless you want to get the top 1% performance of the GPU, you will see no difference compared to a well interleaved vertex. This influence mostly the bandwidth and L2 cache miss, so unless you have crazy millions of particles, it is unlikely to happen. And if you have, you can use a compute shader to interleave the data in a pre-process.

Comment: I thought I could share some words regarding my results. With this approach, I can exclude the shuffling operations completely which previously was consuming most of the frame time. This means that I can store my particle position components in three different arrays and three separate vertex buffers. Just a simple `memcpy` for remapping the vertex data. My previous result was ~80 FPS for 1 million+ particles. Now however I get ~230 FPS for the same amount of particles. Thx again for sharing your knowledge on the subject.